# Installation of Older version QGIS2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 rather than QGIS2.8

Tags: software-installation, versions, tar

I downloaded the qgis2.4 tarball from the qgis website, but it doesn’t follow the typical  3 steps of installation :

```
./configure 
make 
make install
```

So I am stuck and unable to move forward. Could anyone suggest me detailed steps to install qgis2.4 from tarball on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

The QGIS project uses CMake, so you need to run `cmake` to generate the Makefile, followed by `make` to build the application. Based on the way [Ubuntu builds QGIS](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/qgis/vivid/view/head:/debian/rules), you might want to run `cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -D CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=TRUE -D BINDINGS_GLOBAL_INSTALL=TRUE -D PEDANTIC=TRUE -D WITH_SPATIALITE=TRUE -D WITH_MAPSERVER=TRUE-D QGIS_CGIBIN_SUBDIR=/usr/lib/cgi-bin`.

You might also want to install the build dependencies for QGIS. You can do so by running `sudo apt-get build-dep qgis`.

Comment: I am new to this. I am unable to run ./configure or cmake. could u please explain me in detail. I am unable to get your idea. (cmake error is "/home/preetham/QGIS_CGIBIN_SUBD=/usr/lib/cgi-bin” doesn’t exist.